# Python - AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm trying to solve a Sudoku puzzle with open CV package in python. So while I try to call the `solve_sudoku()` function in my main function, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

This is the main code:

```
ans = solve_sudoku(strsudo)
```

This is the solve_sudoku code

```
import time
import random


def cross(A, B):
    "Cross product of elements in A and elements in B."
    return [a+b for a in A for b in B]

digits = '123456789'
rows = 'ABCDEFGHI'
cols = digits
squares = cross(rows, cols)
unitlist = ([cross(rows, c) for c in cols] +
            [cross(r, cols) for r in rows] +
            [cross(rs, cs) for rs in ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
            for cs in ('123', '456', '789')])
units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u]) for s in squares)
# print(units)
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s], []))-set([s])) for s in squares)


def parse_grid(grid):
    """Convert grid to a dict of possible values, {square: digits}, or
    return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    # To start, every square can be any digit;
    # then assign values from the grid.
    values = dict((s, digits) for s in squares)
    for s, d in grid_values(grid).items():
        if d in digits and not assign(values, s, d):
            return False
            # (Fail if we can't assign d to square s.)
    return values


def grid_values(grid):
    "Convert grid into a dict of {square: char} with '0' or '.' for empties."
    chars = [c for c in grid if c in digits or c in '0.']
    assert len(chars) == 81
    return dict(zip(squares, chars))


def assign(values, s, d):
    """Eliminate all the other values (except d) from values[s] and propagate.
    Return values, except return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    other_values = values[s].replace(d, '')
    if all(eliminate(values, s, d2) for d2 in other_values):
        return values
    else:
        return False


def eliminate(values, s, d):
    """Eliminate d from values[s]; propagate when values or places <= 2.
    Return values, except return False if a contradiction is detected."""
    if d not in values[s]:
        return values
        # Already eliminated
    values[s] = values[s].replace(d, '')
    # (1) If a square s is reduced to one value d2,
    # then eliminate d2 from the peers.
    if len(values[s]) == 0:
        return False
        # Contradiction: removed last value
    elif len(values[s]) == 1:
        d2 = values[s]
        if not all(eliminate(values, s2, d2) for s2 in peers[s]):
            return False
    # (2) If a unit u is reduced to only one place for a value d,
    # then put it there.
    for u in units[s]:
        dplaces = [s for s in u if d in values[s]]
        if len(dplaces) == 0:
            return False
            # Contradiction: no place for this value
        elif len(dplaces) == 1:
            # d can only be in one place in unit; assign it there
                if not assign(values, dplaces[0], d):
                    return False
    return values


def display(values):
    "Display these values as a 2-D grid."
    width = 1+max(len(values[s]) for s in squares)
    line = '+'.join(['-'*(width*3)]*3)
    for r in rows:
        print (''.join(values[r+c].center(width)+('|' if c in '36' else '')
               for c in cols))
        if r in 'CF':
            print(line)
    print


def solve(grid): return search(parse_grid(grid))


def search(values):
    "Using depth-first search and propagation, try all possible values."
    if values is False:
        return False
        # Failed earlier
    if all(len(values[s]) == 1 for s in squares):
        return values
        # Solved!
    # Chose the unfilled square s with the fewest possibilities
    n, s = min((len(values[s]), s) for s in squares if len(values[s]) > 1)
    return some(search(assign(values.copy(), s, d))
                for d in values[s])


def some(seq):
    "Return some element of seq that is true."
    for e in seq:
        if e:
            return e
    return False


def solve_all(grids, name='', showif=0.0):
    """Attempt to solve a sequence of grids. Report results.
    When showif is a number of seconds, display puzzles that take longer.
    When showif is None, don't display any puzzles."""
    def time_solve(grid):
        start = time.clock()
        values = solve(grid)
        t = time.clock()-start
        # Display puzzles that take long enough
        if showif is not None and t > showif:
            display(grid_values(grid))
            if values:
                display(values)
            print ('(%.2f seconds)\n' % t)
        return (t, solved(values))
    times, results = zip(*[time_solve(grid) for grid in grids])
    N = len(grids)
    if N > 1:
        print("Solved % d of % d % s puzzles(avg % .2f secs(% d Hz), max % .2f secs)."
              % (sum(results), N, name, sum(times)/N, N/sum(times), max(times)))


def solved(values):
    "A puzzle is solved if each unit is a permutation of the digits 1 to 9."
    def unitsolved(unit): return set(values[s] for s in unit) == set(digits)
    return values is not False and all(unitsolved(unit) for unit in unitlist)


def from_file(filename, sep='\n'):
    "Parse a file into a list of strings, separated by sep."
#    return file(filename).read().strip().split(sep)
    pass


def random_puzzle(N=17):
    """Make a random puzzle by making N assignments. Restart on contradictions.
    Note the resulting puzzle is not guaranteed to be solvable, but empirically
    about 99.8% of them are solvable."""
    values = dict((s, digits) for s in squares)
    for s in random.sample(squares, N):
        if not assign(values, s, random.choice(values[s])):
            return random_puzzle(N)
            # Give up and make a new puzzle
    return ''.join(values[s] if len(values[s]) == 1 else '.' for s in squares)


def shuffled(seq):
    "Return a randomly shuffled copy of the input sequence."
    seq = list(seq)
    random.shuffle(seq)
    return seq


grid1 = '003020600900305001001806400008102900700000008006708200002609500800203009005010300'
grid2 = '4.....8.5.3..........7......2.....6.....8.4......1.......6.3.7.5..2.....1.4......'
hard1 = '.....6....59.....82....8....45........3........6..3.54...325..6..................'
grid3 = '79......3.......6.8.1..4..2..5......3..1......4...62.92...3...6.3.6.5421.........'
extreme ='.26....1.75......2..86.1.9......3....9.4.8.2....1......1.5.92..6......57.3....98.'
# result = solved(grid_values(extreme))


def solve_sudoku(s):
    k = solve(s)
    keys = k.keys()
    keys.sort()
    ans = ''.join(k[i] for i in keys)
    return ans
```

Error:

```
File "C:\....", line 112, in <module>
    ans = solve_sudoku(strsudo)
  File "C:.....", line 182, in solve_sudoku
    keys = k.keys()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: So if you just post a part of your solve_sudoku code...I mean the part with issue, then it's simple for us to find what's wrong. Otherwise your question is little unanswerable. Please check what's [mcve].

Comment: Note that in cutting this down to an MCVE you may solve your own problem! It seems that something you assumed would be a dictionary wasn't...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `parse_grid` is returning `False`, which results in `False` being passed to `search` from `solve`.  So `search` returns `False`, but `solve_sudoku` is failing to check for it.  Just add a check for a `False` return value from `solve` to `solve_sudoku`.

The reason this is happening is because `parse_grid` believes it detected a contradiction, i.e. an inconsistency in the initial state.  Check your `grid` parameter to find the error in your data.